# What is the difference between the openModelFile and openModel commands in Dymola/Modelica?

Tags: modelica, dymola

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441340/how-can-i-add-a-custom-package-to-the-startup-path-in-dymola-modelica), I asked how I can add a custom package to the MODELICAPATH on startup, but there was some ambiguity in the answers.  Based on the answers, I can use either

```
openModel("path\to\file.mo")
```

or

```
openModelFile("Fully.Qualified.Model.Name")
```

I would like to know how these commands differ, if at all, and when to use one or the other.

EDIT: if you answer please provide sources in the Modelica documentation.  I am not sure how to even navigate the documentation to find these commands so this is probably a big handicap.

Comment: These commands are Dymola-specific, so the question should perhaps be edited to reflect that (and for sure no openmodelica tag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chad,

For any questions related to the "built-in" commands in Dymola, please be aware that you can get some basic documentation by using the `document(...)` function (apparently, `help` was too pedestrian and `elucidate` was too pretentious?).  This command can be invoked from the command line on the bottom of the "Simulation" tab in Dymola.  It takes a string of the function name as the argument.  So, to answer your question:

```
document("openModel");

  function openModel "open a Modelica-file"
    input String path "File-path to open";
    input Boolean mustRead := true "If false we can skip reading the file";
    output Boolean result "true if successful";

    "Opens a Modelica-file and pops up a window with the model in it"
  end openModel;

document("openModelFile");

  function openModelFile "open a Modelica-model from a file"
    input String model "Model to open";
    input String path := "" "File-path to open (can be the empty string)";
    input String version := "" "Version to open (can be the empty string)";
    output Boolean result "true if successful";

    "Opens a Modelica-file and pops up a window with the given model in it"
  end openModelFile;
```

Sadly, I don't think the documentation quite captures the difference here.  In fact, I would argue the names are really backward if you think about it.  `openModel` takes a **file** as an argument and opens the definition contained in that file (typically a `package` but not necessarily).  On the other hand, `openModelFile` takes a **model** name as an argument and opens that model in the model browser (searching the [MODELICAPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441340/how-can-i-add-a-custom-package-to-the-startup-path-in-dymola-modelica), if necessary, to find and open the model).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect!  You just taught me how to fish.

Comment: ... in addition to giving me my first fish.

Comment: While `elucidate()`does not (yet?) do anything in Dymola, `help()` is a working command for getting additional help. Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17399473